# Add Sip to proxyaddress attribute in AD using powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, command, microsoft-teams, sip

I have username, and email address.
Couldn’t find a simple command to add sip address in AD attributes.

SIP:emiladdress

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the AD user you want to update then append the ProxyAddresses property (attribute) then set the AD user. I neat and easy way to do this is to use the Active Directory cmdlets instancing feature.

```
$ADUser = Get-ADUser <UserName> -Properties ProxyAddresses

$ADUser.ProxyAddresses = $ADUser.ProxyAddresses += "sip:user@domain.com"

Set-ADUser -Instance $ADUser
```

Comment: No problem.  Please accept the answer, it helps others searching for solutions.